# How to make an array contain a class inherited from a base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the next program, and I have 4 classes:
Cake, PiesandSaltyPastries, IceCreamandDesserts and the base class of all those classes:
CBakery.
I need to make an array contain classes that inherit from CBakery, for example I tried:

```
CBakery *bought[6]; //Bought food 

Cake cake;
cake.InputCake(); //To fill it with input
bought[1] = new Cake;
bought[1] = cake;
```

But it doesnt work, here goes the full code, if you could help me I would be really grateful.

Edit:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class  CBakery
{
public:

    virtual void f(void);

    virtual void Input()
    {
        int freeze;
        cout << "Enter Product Name, Type, Price, if it is freezable(y-1 n-2), and expiration time in days\n";
        cin >> ProductName >> ProductType;
        cin >> ProductPrice;

        cin >> freeze;
        if(freeze == 1)
            freezable = true;
        else
            freezable = false;

        cin >> ExpirationTime;

    }
    virtual void Show(void){        
        cout << "Product's Name: " << ProductName;

        cout << "Product's Type: " << ProductType << "\nProduct's Price: " << ProductPrice << "\nIs Freezable? :";

        if(freezable)
            cout << "Yes\n";
        else
            cout << "Not\n";

        cout << "Expiration time (In days): " << ExpirationTime << endl;

    }

private:

    char *ProductName;
    char ProductType; //1-Salty Pastry. 2-Sweet pastry. 3-Non baked dessert.
    float ProductPrice; // To the customer
    bool freezable; 
    int ExpirationTime; //In days
};

class Cake : public CBakery
{
public:

    void Input()
    {
        CBakery::Input();
        int cream;
        cout << "Does it have cream?\n (1-y, 2-n)\n";
        cin >> cream;

        if(cream = 1)
            Cream = true;
        else
            Cream = false;

        cout << "What is the diameter?(22cm - 24cm - 26cm.....)\n What is the ammount of days to reserve the cake\n";

        cin >> Diameter >> daysToReserve;

    }
    void showCake()
    {
        CBakery::Show();
        cout << "Does it have Cream?\n";
        if (Cream)
            cout << "Yes\n";
        else
            cout << "No\n";

        printf("The Diameter is: %s \n Days needed to reserve the cake are: %s\n", Diameter, daysToReserve);


    }

private:
    bool Cream; 
    char *Diameter; //( 22 cm, 24 cm, 26 cm) Not square cakes.
     char *daysToReserve; 

};

class PiesandSaltyPastries : public CBakery
{
public:
    void Input()
    {
        CBakery::Input();

        int weight, paste;

        cout << "Sold based on weight? (y = 1, n = 2), Contains paste (y = 1, n = 2)?\n";
        cin >> weight >> paste;
        if(weight = 1)
            soldBasedonWeight = true;
        else
            soldBasedonWeight = false;

        if(paste = 1)
            containsPaste = true;
        else
            containsPaste = false;
    }
    void showSalty()
    {
        CBakery::Show();

        cout << "Is it sold based on weight or unities?\n";
        if(soldBasedonWeight)
            cout << "Based on weight\n";
        else
            cout << "Based on unities\n";
    }

private:
    bool soldBasedonWeight; //Weight = true, unity = false.
    bool containsPaste;
};

class IceCreamandDesserts : public CBakery
{
public:
    void Input()
    {
        int natural, milk;
        CBakery::Input();
        cout << "How many calories per unity, is it natural(Y = 1, N = 2) ingredients only?, does it contain milk(Y = 1, N = 2)?\n";

        cin >> caloriesPerUnity;

        cin >> natural >> milk;

        if(natural = 1)
            naturalIngredientsOnly = true;
        else
            naturalIngredientsOnly = false;


        if(milk = 1)
            containsMilk = true;
        else
            containsMilk = false;

    }
    void showDesserts()
    {
        CBakery::Show();
        printf("Calories per unity: %s\n", caloriesPerUnity);

        cout << "Does it have natural ingredients only? \n";
        if(naturalIngredientsOnly)
            cout << "Yes";
        else
            cout << "No";

        cout << "Does it contain milk? \n";
        if(containsMilk)
            cout << "Yes";
        else
            cout << "No";
    }

private:
    char *caloriesPerUnity;
    bool naturalIngredientsOnly;
    bool containsMilk;
};

void main()
{
    CBakery *bought[6];
    char category;


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Is it a cake(1), pies or salty pastry(2), or Ice cream and desserts?(3)\n";
        cin >> category;

        switch(category)
        {
        case 1:

            Cake * cake = new Cake;
            cake -> Input();
            bought[i] = cake;


            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: explain "it doesnt work"

Comment: Doesn't it compile? Did you try with "bought[1] = &cake;"?

Comment: And also. Is Cake a kind of CBakery? If not, please not that you are using inheritance wrongly.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<CBakery>` instead of dealing with fixed size arrays (and pointers!)?

Comment: @crashmstr Object slicing would occur you need the additional indirection for the polymorphism. You can use smart-pointers for the indirection if you like.

Comment: @PeterT oops, you are right! `vector` with smart pointers would be the way to go :)

Comment: To nyaralathotep: after some fixes it says: 
"Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CBakery::f(void)" (?f@CBakery@@UAEXXZ)"

Comment: "it doesn't work" : Let me count the ways...  `if (milk =1 )` and `char *Diameter; ... cin >> Diameter;` are going to fail badly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't state what doesn't work about your program, I'm randomly picking one piece and showing a probable mistake:

```
        Cake cake;
        cake.InputCake();
        bought[i] = new Cake;
```

This piece of code will create a local `Cake` object named `cake`, will call the `InputCake` method on it, and will then insert a completely different, new, dynamically allocated object of type `Cake` into `bought[i]`.

Try this instead:

```
case 1:
{
    Cake * cake = new Cake;
    cake->Input();
    bought[i] = cake;
    break;
}
```

to actually initialize and insert the same object.

Comment: Thank you, I called them all the inputs Input, and I fixed the line class Cake : CBakery, and added the public.

But now it tells me: 
"Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CBakery::f(void)" (?f@CBakery@@UAEXXZ)"

Comment: what do you need the `virtual void f()` for anyway if it seems to be called nowhere? and you have no implementation for it, that's the error the compiler is complaining about here

Comment: Yeah thanks, that was something I forgot to delete, other thing, when It gets to cake -> Input(); it doesn't ask for any input (it just loops the for)

Comment: try to step through it with a debugger. I think it is much more likely that your switch case 1 isn't even entered

Comment: Also it says:
Error 1 error C2360: initialization of 'cake' is skipped by 'case' label.

Comment: so it doesn't even compile ;) huge difference. you're probably still running an old version of your program!

Comment: edited my answer for a fix to that

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for windows desktop.